# Comparing nullable column values using "IS NULL" versus "= NULL"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, null

I'm dealing with nullable values in a column of a table, i'm wondering why this:

```
with cte as (
    select 'c1'::text as c1,null::text as c2
    union
    select 'c2'::text as c1,null::text as c2
)
select *
from cte
where c2 is null
```

returns a result set with the two "rows" having a null value in c2; comparting to this query:

```
with cte as (
    select 'c1'::text as c1,null::text as c2
    union
    select 'c2'::text as c1,null::text as c2
)
select *
from cte
where c2 = null
```

that returns an empty result set!!

so it looks like that `field is null` is actually different from `field = null`? the question is... is there "null-compatible operator" to use? so i can write the comparision like: `column_name = $1` and argument `$1` can be a not null or null value. IF `$1` is a null value then it will semantically equals to write as `IS NULL`, ELSE (if `$1` is not a null value) then it would be semantically equals to `= $1`.

P.D: This question also applies to the case `is NOT NULL` versus `<> NULL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html) it's not possible to use `=` to test for NULL values:

> Ordinary comparison operators yield null (signifying “unknown”), not true or false, when either input is null. For example, 7 = NULL yields null, as does 7 <> NULL.

*is there "null-compatible operator" to use* - Yes, right below the above quote it states:

> When this behavior is not suitable, use the IS [ NOT ] DISTINCT FROM predicates

So you can use

```
where c2 is not distinct from $1
```

One drawback of the IS DISTINCT or IS NOT DISTINCT operator is however, that they can't use an index.

Comment: Once again! THanks for the info wandering horse!

Comment: Not that it is commendable, but there is a compatibility parameter `transform_null_equals` that will convert `= NULL` to `IS NULL`.

Comment: THanks @LaurenzAlbe, i guess i'm not the first persons facing this problem... so any advise about a proved solution to go on with this, is more than welcome!

Comment: Use `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` like @a_horse_with_no_name recommends.